# Chrome extension: Not downloading after clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to download a file to my downloads file. I'm creating a button on the web-page dynamically and id like to download something when that button is pressed. For what ever reason when I click the button nothing happens and I don't know why. Please help

background.js code

```
function SendRequest(url, callback){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

var objurl = localStorage.getItem("OBJURL");
function EditContent(objurl){
    chrome.downloads.download({url:objurl,filename:"Object Edit - Chrome Extension.rbxl",conflictAction:"overwrite"})
}
```

item.js

```
contentInput.onclick = function(){
var assetid = $('.thumbnail-span').attr("data-3d-url")
var baseurl = 'http://www.roblox.com'
SendRequest(baseurl + assetid, function (response) { 
 var response = response; //Easy Peasy
 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response); //Parse the response

 localStorage.setItem("URL1", jsonObject.Url); //It's saved!
 var test = localStorage.getItem("URL1"); //Let's grab it and save it to a variable
 console.log(test); //Logs "Hello World!"
});

var url1 = localStorage.getItem("URL1");
SendRequest(url1, function (response1) {

var response = response1; //Easy Peasy
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response); //Parse the response
localStorage.setItem("OBJ", jsonObject.obj); //It's saved!
});

var hashdecode = "http://roblox.com/thumbnail/resolve-hash/"
var objhash = localStorage.getItem("OBJ");
SendRequest(hashdecode + objhash, function (objresponse) { 
var response = objresponse; //Easy Peasy
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response); //Parse the response

localStorage.setItem("OBJURL", jsonObject.Url); //It's saved!
});



    chrome.extension.sendRequest({
        action: "EditContent",

    })

}
```

Comment: What is it what all the roblox questions lately?..

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy. There's a lot wrong here. And I mean ***a lot***.

1. `chrome.extension.sendRequest` is deprecated. Use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` instead.
2. That said, you're sending the message, but nothing actually listens to it. `action: "something"` doesn't mean anything a priori, you need to react to that yourself:

   ```
   // background.js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
     function(message, sender, sendResponse){
       if(message.action == "EditContent") {
         /* do stuff */
       }
     }
   );
   ```
3. `localStorage` is NOT shared between the content script and the background script. In fact, background script has its own copy of `localStorage` (bound to `chrome-extension://whateverisyourid/` domain) and the content script shares it with the page.

   You should either use `chrome.storage`, which is shared but works differently, or pass what you need in the message, i.e. a message like:

   ```
   {action: "EditContent", objurl: jsonObject.Url}
   ```

   And use it:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
     function(message, sender, sendResponse){
       if(message.action == "EditContent") {
         EditContent(message.objurl)
       }
     }
   );
   ```
4. A function defined in the background script (`SendRequest`) **cannot** be called in the content script. You need to move it to the content script, or call it from the background script.
5. Your `SendRequest` is asynchronous. If you write something like:

   ```
   function f(){
     action1();
     SendRequest(url1, function(response){
       action2();
     });
     action3();
     SendRequest(url2, function(response){
       action4();
     });
     action5();
   }

   f();
   ```

   then this is what will happen:

   - `action1()`
   - `SendRequest` will queue a request with `url1`, but not wait for it
   - `action3()`
   - `SendRequest` will queue a request with `url2`, but not wait for it
   - `action5()`
   - Your function `f()` terminates, next in queue is the first request.
   - When the request finishes, `action2()` is run.
   - Next in queue is the second request.
   - When the request finishes, `action4()` is run.

   This might even get swapped, I suppose, depending on which request finishes first.

   You see the problem? You need to chain asynchronous calls instead:

   ```
   function f(){
     action1();
     SendRequest(url1, function(response){
       action2();
       action3();
       SendRequest(url2, function(response){
         action4();
         action5();
       });
     });
   }
   ```

This might not be the full list of problems, and certainly is not a full working code.

Please, *please* debug your extensions next time. You can access errors from the content script in the page's console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), and background page's console from `chrome://extensions` in Developer Mode.